# Vector similarity and probability

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I hope it is suitable forum for this kind of question.
I'm implementing wifi location functionality in a mobile app based on RSSI of WiFi network. I'm saving available access points and received signal (in dB) as a vector and then comparing it with scanned network in different location. 
For example:
saved fingerprint:
{AP1: -30,
AP2: -45,
AP3: -60}

scanned location:
{AP1: -25,
AP3: -65,
AP4: -70}

Should I add and create a scanned location vector to contain the same access points when they are not in the scanned vector? For example AP2 with -120 which is the lowest value?

What is the best way to compare multidimensional vectors and calculate probability of matching vectors based on the similarity?
I was thinking about two methods - Euclidean distance and cosine similarity but they are much different and wanted to know which is more practical to implement in this case? Maybe there is something that I didn't heard of? I looked at papers related to this problem and there is not much but I noticed that Euclidean one was chose quite often.

EDIT about probability:
for example saved fingerprint: [-30, -45, -60] and [-35, -40, -55] and comparing it with scanned vector: [-30, -45, -55] so just by looking by the numbers we can tell that it is more similar to the first one but we can't tell it is 100% the first one.

Comment: I don't think this is the appropriate forum for your question unless you can turn it into a more specific math question. Sure you can calculate the difference between vectors (points) and the angle between them. How do you want to turn this into probability? I don't see the connection between location comparing and probability here. Can you clarify the situation any?

Comment: @jdods have a look at the edit

Comment: It's more clarified, but in order to bring in the idea of probability we need more info. Maybe assume the signal deviation is a standard normal random variable, it maybe use a known variance for such signals. Then calculate the probability of having a deviation of 5 or greater. Assume each 3 parts of the signal are independent.